# What does いや、これで見つからないと俺としましては逆に大変なことになるのですmean?

Tags: meaning, conjugations

Could someone help with the gramatical construction of this phrase?

> いや、これで見つからないと俺としましては逆に大変なことになるのです

What I don't get is the としまして part
Could someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In meaning,

> 「俺｛おれ｝と**しまして**は」＝「俺と**して**は」

The former is politer than the latter for using 「します」 rather than just 「する」, which the latter uses.

Strictly speaking, that makes the sentence in question sound a little bit off-balanced because 「俺」 is not very polite to begin with.

In fiction, however, one would expect to encounter expressions like this more often than in real life.  In real life, you would hear 「俺としては」 considerably more often than 「俺としましては」.

Both mean "**as for me**", "**as far as I am concerned**", etc.

Comment: What is the verb here? する? How did it conjugate to しまして? する -> します -> しまして?

Comment: @Sweeper See 3-㋒ of http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120514/meaning/m0u/