# Can someone explain to me how "としまして" is formed?

Tags: grammar, て-form, potential-form, form

Could someone help me by explaining how this is formed?

The question here refers to an answer to my question (second comment on answer), but I don't understand it:
[Could someone help with the gramatical construction of this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42780/could-someone-help-with-the-gramatical-construction-of-this-phrase)

Answer (3-㋒): https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120514/meaning/m0u/

It looks like someone transformed a masu-form verb to a "masu-te"-form, which I never heared of:

> する、します、しまして
>   たべる、たべます、たべまして

If I am not mistaken, the referenced answer also talks about the potential form. How does this relate? Furthermore, is this construction in any way related to はじめまして?